# Scrolling notification menu (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried to make a vertscrolling div for my notification div (it's a not displayed div until the notification icon is pressed) using HTML and CSS and it failed, in chrome at least the browser shows me the scrolling bar but I cannot control it (can't slide that rectangle and when I click the arrows nothing happens) **I have tried the overflow-y propriety and the scrolling propriety** but nothing works FYI I have 4 notification boxes that are on top of each others and only shown when the proper icon is clicked (one for notifications, one for messages , another for friendship requests and a last one for forum notifications) HTML is this :

```
<div id="infoNot" >
  <ul>
      <a href=''><li>Foulan a accépter votre demande d'amitié</li></a>
      <a href=''><li>Foulan a poster dans le forum</li></a>
      <a href=''><li>Foulan a bla bla bla</li></a>
      <a href=''><li>Foulan a accépter votre demande d'amitié</li></a>
      <a href=''><li>Foulan a poster dans le forum</li></a>
      <a href=''><li>Foulan a bla bla bla</li></a>
      <a href=''><li>Foulan a accépter votre demande d'amitié</li></a>
      <a href=''><li>Foulan a poster dans le forum</li></a>
      <a href=''><li>Foulan a bla bla bla</li></a>
      <a href=''><li>Foulan a accépter votre demande d'amitié</li></a>
      <a href=''><li>Foulan a poster dans le forum</li></a>
      <a href=''><li>Foulan a bla bla bla</li></a>
      <a href=''><li>Foulan a accépter votre demande d'amitié</li></a>
      <a href=''><li>Foulan a poster dans le forum</li></a>
      <a href=''><li>Foulan a bla bla bla</li></a>
      <a href='' class="cMore">
      <li class="cMore">Voir toutes les notifications</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="infoMsg">
  <ul>
      <li><img src='media/images/icons/msg.png'><p class="sender">YOLO</p>
      <p class="description">Salut, Cava? wi non pas bien</p><span></span></li>
      <li><img src='media/images/icons/msg.png'><p>Salut</p><span></span></li>
      <li><img src='media/images/icons/msg.png'><p>Salut</p><span></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="infoForum">
  <ul>
      <a href=''><li>Foulan a repondu à votre poste dans le forum</li></a>
      <a href=''><li>L'admin a supprimer votre sujet</li></a>
      <a href=''><li>bla bla bla</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="infoFR">
   <ul>
     <a href=''><li>Foulan foulani veut étre votre ami</li></a>
     <a href=''><li>Fataan foulani veut étre votre ami</li></a>
     <a href=''><li>Mr. X foulani veut étre votre ami</li></a>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#infoNot , #infoMsg , #infoForum , #infoFR
{
    top:50px;
    left:10px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 5px;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
#infoMsg
{
    left:25px;
    height: 500px;
}
#infoNot ul , #infoMsg ul , #infoForum ul , #infoFR ul
{
    list-style: none;
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
#infoNot ul a
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
#infoNot ul a:nth-child(even)
{
    color: #595959;
    background-color: #a1a1a1;
}
#infoNot ul a:nth-child(odd)
{
    color: #a1a1a1;
    background-color: #595959;
}
#infoNot ul a:hover
{
    background-color: #818181;
}
#infoMsg ul li img
{
    float:left;
    display: block;
}
#infoMsg ul li
{
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-buttom:3px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c2;
}
#infoMsg span
{
    clear:both;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: For reference, it's semantically incorrect for `a` elements to be children of `ul` elements. Your current set up has `ul` containing `a` containing `li`. You'll want to put those anchor tags *within* your list item tags.

Comment: Thank you, but, I've changed that and it didn't help